# Method for calculating volume under a surface in R

Tags: r, surface, auc

I'm trying to calculate the volume under a 3d surface in `R`.

My data, `dat`, looks like:

```
          0.003     0.019     0.083      0.25       0.5         1
0     1.0000000 0.8884265 0.8603268 0.7719994 0.7443621 0.6571405
0.111 0.6909722 0.6775000 0.6443750 0.6243750 0.5914730 0.5698242
0.25  0.5847205 0.6022367 0.5572917 0.5432991 0.5170673 0.4835819
0.429 0.5210938 0.5139063 0.4995312 0.4864062 0.4648636 0.4163698
0.667 0.4363103 0.4526562 0.4321859 0.4027519 0.4046011 0.3661616
1     0.3958333 0.4167468 0.3964428 0.3810459 0.3486328 0.3487930
```

where `x = rownames(dat)`, `y = colnames(dat)` and `z = dat`.

I've looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14515291/volume-from-the-surface-down-to-a-contour-in-r?rq=1), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16381903/calculating-the-volume-under-a-surface), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45750035/how-to-calculate-the-volume-under-a-surface-defined-by-discrete-data?noredirect=1&lq=1), but can't seem to figure out how to apply those answers to my use case.

Here's a reproducible version of my data:

```
dat = structure(c(1,0.690972222222222,0.584720477386935,0.52109375,0.436310279187817,0.395833333333333,0.888426507537688,0.6775,0.602236675126904,0.51390625,0.45265625,0.416746794871795,0.860326776649746, 0.644375, 0.557291666666667,0.49953125,0.432185913705584,0.396442819148936,0.771999378109453,0.624375,0.543299129353234,0.48640625,0.402751865671642,0.381045854271357,0.744362113402062,0.591472989949749,0.517067307692308,0.464863578680203,0.404601130653266,0.3486328125,0.657140544041451,0.56982421875,0.483581852791878,0.41636981865285,0.366161616161616,0.348792989417989),.Dim = c(6L, 6L), .Dimnames = list(c("0","0.111","0.25","0.429","0.667","1"),c("0.003","0.019","0.083","0.25","0.5","1")))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `getVolume()` function provided in the answer you linked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45750035/how-to-calculate-the-volume-under-a-surface-defined-by-discrete-data?noredirect=1&lq=1#answer-45781387) provided that your matrix were in the requisite dataframe format.

Here is some code to make that dataframe:

```
df <- expand.grid(x = as.numeric(rownames(dat)), y = as.numeric(colnames(dat)))
df$z = as.vector(dat)
```

Then define the function and apply:

```
library(geometry)

getVolume=function(df) {
  #find triangular tesselation of (x,y) grid
  res=delaunayn(as.matrix(df[,-3]),full=TRUE,options="Qz")
  #calulates sum of truncated prism volumes
  sum(mapply(function(triPoints,A) A/3*sum(df[triPoints,"z"]),
             split.data.frame(res$tri,seq_along(res$areas)),
             res$areas))
}

getVolume(df)
```

[1] 0.4714882